How to actually select only odd or even rows from a selection in LibreOffice Calc?
There is a post How to select odd or even rows in Calc? - English - Ask LibreOffice, which unfortunately does not answer the question as posed (the answer talks about conditional formatting).
What I instead want to do is:

Make a selection - select a range of cells with the mouse (say R1C1:R7C4)


Run some sort of a command shortcut/dialog/filter where I can say "I just want the even rows from the current selection, relative to the top-left start of the selection")

Then my original selection is reset, and what remains is the selection of R2C1:R2C4 and R4C1:R4C4 and R6C1:R6C4, as if I control-clicked any of those cells individually



Is it possible to do something like this in LibreOffice Calc?

Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451040/delete-alternate-lines-in-a-csv-file-libreoffice-calc can help, using =ISODD(ROW()) and =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()*2-1;1)

Though, AFAIK, one cannot change the rows selected by either mouse or keyboard, one can specify operations performed on the basis of row number (or column number). One could include only certain rows' text or values, and exclude others.
For example, to make separate sums of even rows and of odd rows:

Use Row(), IsOdd() and IsEven() functions to make two columns of Boolean TRUE/FALSE based on even or odd row.
Multiply Boolean (TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0) by value in number column.
Sum Even and Odd columns.

Example:


A2 * FALSE = 0, so Prod(odd) D2 = 0
A2 * TRUE = 3, so Prod(even) E3 = 3

This answer is an adaptation of pnuts answer for a similar question.

Thanks - good to know there are ISODD/ISEVEN functions - but this does not answer the question as posed. Can I use these ISODD/ISEVEN function to modify a selection made with the mouse, like shown in the screenshots in the OP?

AFAIK, there is no way to change a selection made by mouse, or keyboard, but one can operate on that selection to only include data from odd/even rows.
